# Python inheritance display nodes from some edge

Tags: python, oop

I tried build these classes and I need to display every node of an edge.
(state of a node is just a number 1 or 0 (visited/not visited)).

I have to build a graph (undirected) and manage all edges (display edge, change state of a node of an edge etc.)

The problem is in class Edge on method getNode1()

```
class Nodee:

   def __init__(self, node, state):
      self.node = node
      self.state = state

   def getNode(self):
         return self.node

   def getStateNode(self):
         return self.state


class Edge(Nodee):

      def __init__(self, node1, node2):
         Nodee.__init__(self,node1,0)
         Nodee.__init__(self,node2,0)

      def getNode1(self):
         return self.node1.getNode()

      def getStateNode1(self):
         return self.node1.getStateNode()

      def getNode2(self):
         return self.node2.getNode()

      def getStateNode2(self):
         return self.node2.getStateNode()

def main():

      graf = []
      node1  = Nodee(2,0)
      node2  = Nodee(1,0)

      graf.append(Edge(node1,node2))
      print(str(node1.getNode()))
      print(str(graf[0].getNode1()))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display every node"? Do you want a string representation of an object? For this you could implement the ``__str__`` function.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, display node with print, like print(graf[0].getNode1())

Comment: I could not understand what it your intentions. You need to explain your aim much more clearly.

Comment: in class "Edge" methods like getNode1() doesn't give the node1 from an edge. I don't know how to build it correctly (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Your second class `Edge` do not have any node1 instance variable. In your init you need to do `self.node1 = Nodee.__init__(self,node1,0)` and repeat for node2. Then you will not get this error. But in that case do you really need inheritance for that?

Comment: @scriptmonster yes, because then i need to add a specific cost of each edge (but this is another problem). Now, with your correction I don't have errors but it doesn't displays "2". In command line it displays an empty line

Comment: Please check my answer, look at the last if block which runs your main code. Since all of your codes are inside methods, it won't directly run. You need some other block to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't understand what inheritance is.

Your code do not have node1 and node2 instance variables. 
Which is the main problem. 
If the following code covers your needs you don't need any inheritance.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, node, state):
        self.node = node
        self.state = state

    def get_node(self):
        return self.node

    def get_state_node(self):
        return self.state


class Edge(object):

    def __init__(self, node1, node2):
        self.nodes = []
        self.nodes.append(node1)
        self.nodes.append(node2)

    def get_node(self, index):
        return self.nodes[index].get_node()

    def get_state_node(self, index):
        return self.nodes[index].get_state_node()


def main():
    graf = []
    node1  = Node(2,0)
    node2  = Node(1,0)

    graf.append(Edge(node1,node2))
    print(node1.get_node())
    print(graf[0].get_node(0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> If you are writing code in python, then there are some conventions, please look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).